# Java - Product of rows only and full 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, product

I have a 2d array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] array2d = new int[][]{
        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
        {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20},
        {1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100},
        {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
        {1, 4, 9, 16, 9, 7, 4, 9, 11},
        {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1},
        {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
    };
```

1.) I need to get the product of each row alone. So I need to get product of row 1, row 2, row 3, row 4, etc. and print them out. Then I need to get the product of the whole entire 2d array and print that. How do I do that? I have been trying at it for like 2 hours now and had no luck :(

2.) I need to display the number of 2's in each row of the array, and as well display the total number of 2's in this array. How can I do that?

This is what I have so far...

```
public static void taskTwo(int[][] array2d) {
        int prod = 1;
        for(int i=0;i<array2d.length;i++) 
        {
        prod = array2d[i][0] * array2d[i][1];   
    System.out.println("");
    String productFixed = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().format(prod);
    System.out.println("The product is: " +productFixed);
```

Comment: Show what you have tried to help you find what's wrong with it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This sounds more like a homework assignment that you want to get done. Show us some sample code that you've tried and where it failed.

Comment: edited. I don't understand why random people down vote my question just so I cant ask questions anymore lol.

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.out.println("Product of element of each row");
    // for each one-D (s)array do following
    for(int[]s : array2d){
        long product = 1;
        // for each int (i) in one-D array do following
        for(int i:s){
            product  = product * i;
        }
        System.out.println(product);
    }
```

As said this seems to be a assignment problem so i am posting a small part of problem with little description. Hope it will help you in solving the problem.